# Live feed: Don't know how to save what gets submitted

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

The feed itself works but with the intervals on it updates itself and when I submit something it refreshes the page and nothing gets saved.

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval("showNewStories()", 5000);
});

function showNewStories() {
    $.getJSON("post.php", null, function(data) {
        if (data != null) {
            $("#stories").prepend($("<li><span class=\"story\">" + 
                data.story + "<br /><span class=\"date\">" + data.date + 
                "</span></li>").fadeIn("slow"));
        }
    });}
```

post.php:

```
<?php 
echo json_encode(array( "story" => $_POST['dataS'],
                                        "date" => date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')));
?>
```

What I want to know is how I can have it like Facebook's feed where you submit something, it gets added to the feed, and then it stays there even if you refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a php expert, so I can't tell if you are already doing this, but the code on the server side should accept a parameter which will tell it what date to load the posts from.

You should then have a variable in the javascript on the client side indicating the date/time of the latest post retrieved.  When the page loads, this should be null.

Then, the call to `showNewStories` would send the variable with the last datetime to the server.  On the server, if the variable is passed to the php page, then it will return *only* the posts where the date time posted is *greater* than the date/time posted.

Then, when you get the response from the server, you can add the posts to your timeline.  When you add the last one, you store *that* date time as the date time that will be passed to the server the next time that `showNewStories` is called.

There is a hole in this logic in that if the resolution of the date time on your server is not fine enough to handle the frequency of the number of posts it receives, you could run into an issue where a post is made at time `x`, you retrieve the list up to time `x`, and then another post is accepted at time `x`.  The next time `showNewStories` makes a call to the server, you will miss the second post made at time `x`.

To make this bullet-proof, you would change the logic on the server to include any posts where the post time is equal to the date time passed in.  You would also return a unique id for each post passed back to the client.

Then, on the client-side, when the callback to `getJSON` is called, you would include any items where the date time of the post is greater than the time submitted to the server *or* the date times are equal, and the post id returned from the server isn't already in the list (I'd recommend including the id of the post in the list as a [data attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)).

Answer (score 0):

how are you storing the data on the server? The data will need to be stored somewhere, likely a database to make it easy to get the most recent few.

Comment: I don't have any method to storing the data because, to be honest, I have no clue as to how.

Comment: Unless your application will only ever have a single user, you're going to need to store the data somewhere to persist data between requests. A really simple way to store the data would be to use `file_put_contents()` and `serialize()` to store the PHP data on disk.